# Validar inputs en formulario de cambio de contraseñas con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo un formulario de cambio de contraseña en HTML, el cual es el siguiente:

```html
<form id="needs-validation" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Contraseña actual</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña actual" type="password"  id = "oldpw" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Nueva contraseña</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa la nueva contraseña" type="password" id = "newpw" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Repetir nueva contraseña</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Repite la nueva contraseña" type="password"  id = "confirmpw" required>
</div>

<p class="mb-4" style="color: #FF0000" id = "campo"></p>
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Cambiar contraseña</button>

<small class="text-muted mt-5 mb-1 d-block">Volver al <a href="/">panel de control</a></small>
</form>
```

Al hacer *submit* me funciona el marcar en rojo los cuadros de texto si están vacíos, pero quiero que al cambiar el campo "confirmpw" me verifique si es igual al campo "newpw", lo quiero hacer mediante la función "keypress" pero no sé como marcar el campo "newpw" en rojo, como cuando se hace submit y está vacío.

Adjuntaré una imagen de lo que quiero lograr.

[Imagen](https://prnt.sc/pa4ghi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `setCustomValidity()` de la siguiente manera:

```js
var password = document.getElementById("newpw"); 
var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirmpw");

function validatePassword(){
  if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
    //Colorear confirm en rojo o usar:
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Las contraseñas no coinciden");
  } else {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

```html
<form id="needs-validation" >
<div class="form-group">
<label>Contraseña actual</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña actual" type="password"  id = "oldpw" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Nueva contraseña</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ingresa la nueva contraseña" type="password" id = "newpw" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Repetir nueva contraseña</label>
<input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Repite la nueva contraseña" type="password"  id = "confirmpw" required>
</div>

<p class="mb-4" style="color: #FF0000" id = "campo"></p>
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Cambiar contraseña</button>

<small class="text-muted mt-5 mb-1 d-block">Volver al <a href="/">panel de control</a></small>
</form>
```

Solo sería necesario agregar el código para poner los input en rojo.